# Motion software for IP web camera loosing connection on browser

Tags: raspberry-pi, 3g, motion

I am using motion software on the pi to monitor video in a room.
I am having some problems. whenever the raspberry pi camera board detects motion, the red light on the camera board flashes, and the video feed on the browser tries to refresh, but it says cant load page. The again, i have to refresh the page to get it going again. Then, again if the camera senses motion (for ex, a person moves near to it) the browser loses connection. I have to refresh again.

The framerate I am using is 100.

Answer (score 0):

I'm achieving rather good results with [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/665518/Raspberry-Pi-as-low-cost-HD-surveillance-camera) documentation. I'm not sure if you tried that or if you're using a different setup, but maybe this helps. Also, I'm not using 100 fps. I set mine to 10. Don't know if the cam is even capable of 100 fps. Or if it's necessary. Compare it to the different tv formats [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_rate).

Hope this helps.